# List items not displaying?

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code, but currently, the values are not displaying:

```
<select>
  <options value="volvo">Volvo</options>
  <options value="saab">Saab</options>
  <options value="mercedes">Mercedes</options>
  <options value="audi">Audi</options>
</select>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: change options to option and it should work

Comment: @user125697 It happens ;) no one's born talented

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using wrong tag.
It is  `<option></option>` not `<options></options>`.